# Head to tail transistor pair, not a Darlington pair, not a Szlikai Darlington

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, bjt, npn

I recently reversed engineered a discrete voltage regulator from a board that was performing quite well, and I stumbled upon a weird transistor pair circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7DSh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The zener D1 is a TL431 shunt regulator in the real circuit. I put a 5.8V zener just to make the simulation works.

I looked for some time in the literature and dug into some schematics and cannot find any references to that kind of transistor pair. Does they have a name ? What would be the advantage of such an arrangement versus a simple BJT or even a Darlington?

Comment: There is nothing weird in this "pair". It is the well-known current protection (see, for example, the 741 output stage). The current threshold is set by the value of R1.

Comment: R3 C1 should connect to the right of R5 if regulation is not to suffer from loading. R5 drops 0.1 v per mA which wrecks regulation.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Indeed, but there is actually another 100R resistor after C3 in the original circuit. The current load is very low. The only purpose of the circuit is to energize an OPA337 that is driving small capacitors, so virtually no load.
Edit: also, you would loose the filtering effect of R5 C3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see in the OP's circuit diagram is a reference voltage source (implemented by R2 and D1), emitter follower (Q1) and a current-limiting circuit (Q2 and R1).

The load current "creates" a voltage drop VR1 across R1. At normal conditions, it is less than 0.7 V (the voltage threshold of the protection circuit), and Q2 is cut-off. The output voltage Vreg follows the unregulated input voltage V1.

When the voltage drop exceeds the voltage threshold (approximately 0.7 V), Q2 turns on and begins diverting Q1's base current. Thus the load current is limited.

This circuit solution is widely used in the output stages of power and op-amp amplifiers (see, for example, the [741 output stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op_amp)).

Comment: Ah thanks, it totally makes sense now. I had a hard time figuring how the Q2 current was not raising the shunt regulator voltage. Now I get it, Q1 base current is just dumped to the output.